# Web workers and accessing object attached to the window object

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have an ember application that I create like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});
```

I want to do some background processing on a web worker.

How can I get access to the window object or some other global object in the separate web worker thread?

Comment: Can you use `postMessage()` to send state back?

Comment: I can but does that not pass context back to the main thread?

Comment: Yeah. From what I can gather, you're supposed to do things on a new thread with no immediate side effects on the main thread.

Comment: What I am trying to do is load an object with json and have it available later.  Should I put the data into local storage as trying to update the store on the new thread has side effects.

Answer (score 18):

Short answer. You can't.

The only resources available to web workers are that which they load from JavaScript files using `importScripts()` or anything that is passed to them via `postMessage()`.

You can however now pass Objects to them. They are serialized and de-serialized to JSON automatically.

Also, there is no access to local storage from the Worker.

Comment: Do you know if I call importScripts, would the window object be available in the inmported script?

Comment: You can have **no access to the window Object from a worker.**

Comment: @dagda1 Try having a look at the [web worker tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers).

Comment: if I call self.postMessage from the web worker, does that push context back to the main UI thread or is it still on the worker thread?

Comment: @dagda1 Do you mean scope? The scope of `postMessage()` will be the Worker Object.

Comment: I mean which thread will it be running on after the web worker has called self.postMessage() and the onMessage callback is invoked, is the execution returned to the UI thread?  I am assuming yes because the window object is accessible in this handler.

Comment: Everything is handled by callbacks in the appropriate threads.